# How can i get the all coupons details in magento 2 using api?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I want to get all coupons that i created in the price rule section using the API just like the result of product/orders listing API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET on "/V1/coupons/search"

Comment: What should be the search criteria?

Comment: Depends on what you are searching for. if you want to get "all" as you stated in the question, you don't need a search criteria

Comment: But when I tried this without any search criteria, I get missing filename error.

Comment: I have found the answer :
`rest/V1/coupons/search?searchCriteria=all`
From the above API, i got all the coupon codes, then i picked the rule_id which is 5 and put in the below API for getting details of that particular API
`/rest/V1/salesRules/5`

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use the following to get all the coupon codes via REST API.

```
GET     -   {{url_rest_api}}/rest/V1/coupons/search?searchCriteria=all      
Auth    -   Bearer Token = ###

Body    -     Blank 

Response
{
    "items": [
        {
            "coupon_id": 2,
            "rule_id": 5,
            "code": "TEST123",
            "times_used": 0,
            "is_primary": true,
            "type": 0
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": []
    },
    "total_count": 1
}
```